# Trying to read outlook attachments with python

Tags: python, outlook

I am working on a script that reads emails from Outlook using Python, I wanted to know if there is any way to read the attachments without downloading them, for example open an attached pdf and capture it in a DataFrame.

This is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import os

mail ='email_name@gmail.com'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

stores = outlook.Stores
for store in stores:
        if store.DisplayName == mail:
                inbox = store.GetDefaultFolder(6)
                messages = inbox.Items
                for attachment in messages[1].Attachments:
                        print(attachment)
```

Comment: I do not know very well why my greeting was deleted when I posted.

Hello Community.

Answer (score 1):

> any way to read the attachments without downloading them

No. You need to [save the file on the disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) first. Then you can open the just saved file on the disk and process it in your application.

```
# Creating an object for the message.Attachments.
attachment = message.Attachments
# To check which item is selected among the attacments.
print (message.Attachments.Item(which_item))
# To iterate through email items using message.Attachments object.
for attachment in message.Attachments:
   # To save the perticular attachment at the desired location in your hard disk.
   attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join("D:\Script\Attachments",file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model does not provide access to the attachment binary data. The best you can do is save the attachment as a temporary file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), read file contents, delete the file.

On the MAPI level however (C++ or Delphi only), attachments can only be accessed as blobs or as `IStream` (or `IStorage`) interface; MAPI knows nothing about files. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it provides access to the attachment data through the `AsText` / `AsArray` / `EmbeddedMsg` / `OleStorage` / `AsStream` properties - see https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm and https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_Attachment.htm